# How to find id of the web page element using its table id in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

My application has a grid with multiple rows. The rows have edit option which loads another page to update the personal information. The row edit icon id is:

```
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00_ctl20_EditButton"
```

If we click this icon the personal page opens. The elements in the personal page is start with 
`"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00_ctl21_txtFirstName"` which is based on the edit icon id.

The problem is that I can click the edit icon with table id concepts. The command is:

```
selenium.click("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00']
//tr[td[.='"kannan"']]/td/input[@type='image']");
```

But I was unable to get the id of the edit icon.

If I get the id of the edit icon, I can easily change personal page elements id by adding "1" in edit icon id.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: this is not whatsapp, please write correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use only id

```
selenium.click("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
  public ArrayList<String> IdsOfEditOption()
{
   WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00"));
   WebElement tbody=table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
   List<WebElement> rows=tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   ArrayList<String> ListOdIds=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement EditOption = tbody.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdEmployeeMaster_ctl00']/tbody/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
     String EditOptionId=EditOption.getAttribute("id");
     ListOdIds.add(EditOptionId);
   }

   return ListOdIds;
}
```

Comment: In this firstly we are finding the table,then its tbody and then all the rows present in the tbody tag. Then we are finding edit option button in each row(we assume that edit option button is present in the first column that's why we use td at the end if it is present in the 2 or 3 column change it to as td[2] or td[3] ). Then we are finding one edit option and we are getting it's attribute id and then store it into the array list. This way we will have list of all ids of the edit option button.